# How to show content belonging to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I switched from showing the user id in the params to having the username in the params. I could use some help in my Users controller show action for listing Questions from the current user.

For example the user "Monkey" has an id of 5. I visit their page /users/monkey. It should list all questions from that user only. This work prior to adding the username to the params.

How should I modify `recipient_id: params[:id]`?

Users controller:

```
 def show
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
    @question = Question.where(recipient_id: params[:id]).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
```

The current setup will not display anything. If I specify the user id such as `recipient_id: 5` in the show action it will display the Questions from that user (though it will show the same Questions on all user show pages). It no longer works using params id since the params is containing the username now instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `@user.id` instead of `params[:id]` like

```
@user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
@question = Question.where(recipient_id: @user.id).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)

                    **OR**

@question = @user.questions.page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
```

Comment: yup, that would be more appropriate.

Comment: I forgot to add `@`. Silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @BradWerth Good thinking, that is better.